# Power supply starts then stops under no load test

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to see whether a power supply I have got is working.
I connected the green pin to black with a paperclip. The only other connection is to the mains.

When I switch it on, the fan starts up, but then stops after a second or 2. Switching off and back on causes no activity.

If I remove the paperclip and put it back, the fan starts for another 2 seconds.

Is my ps shot, or is it supposed to do that without a mobo connected?

Comment: It's a hec-550td-pte

Comment: Buy a power supply tester - they're not that expensive.

Comment: Buy a power supply tester   ....  This is probably the best way. The only other way I know is to kook up the supply and measure test points with a decent voltmeter.

Comment: You can't do it with a voltmeter, because it doesn't test under load. If you can get a dedicated PSU tester, get one… but watch out, many of the cheap testers don't apply load either.

Comment: Yes, you must apply a load but that should be fairly easy to simulate.

Comment: @John - really… how? I'm serious on this, for 10 years I worked as a maintenance engineer. Because we couldn't persuade the company to build us load testers specific to the devices, all we could do for a suspect PSU was replace it. If it was that easy, we'd have done it another way.

Comment: really… how?  ... There is an output connector on the supply. You should be able to calculate a load resistor for the different voltages (different resistors).  Carefully connect and test the voltage across. Delicate operation but that is how I test power supplies for different electronic gear on my workbench.

Comment: That assumes you know what the resistances should be

Comment: If you have a 12 volt supply line, then a 24 ohm resistor will draw 1/2 amp and that should be sufficient load to do a test.